# Scikit-learn ValueError: unknown is not supported when using confusion matrix

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm using the confusion_matrix module to visualize class prediction results compared to actual values.

```
val= ... #shape (3000,1,30) dtype float32
pred = ... #shape (3000,1,30) dtype float32

cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(val, pred) #ERROR HERE
```

I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "vis.py", line 757, in
>       cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)   File "C:\Anaconda\envs\nn35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py",
>   line 240, in confusion_matrix
>       y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)   File "C:\Anaconda\envs\nn35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py",
>   line 89, in _check_targets
>       raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type)) ValueError: unknown is not supported

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Problem was the shape of the true value and prediction must be (3000,30) not (3000,1,30). So I reshape it using `pred= np.reshape(pred, (pred.shape[0],  30))`